# Binary functions using only addition and bitwise NOT

Tags: assembly, binary, logic, minecraft, cpu-architecture

So, I working on a minecraft redstone computer project, implementing my own CPU in HEX(analog redstone). I managed to implement an arithmetic ADD and bitwise NOT functions, and also conditional jumping. The functions are 4-bit bitwise. But with hex redstone it is hard to make other logical functions compact. So, my question is, can it be turing complete with only those functions? And, if yes, how can I implement other logical functions (like AND, OR, XOR) using only those?

Comment: Turing complete doesn't necessarily imply that.  e.g. an implementation of a C program that does `x ^ y` on `int` variables might need to handle those ints one bit at a time.  (e.g. the low bit of an ADD is the XOR of the low bits of the inputs, because there's no carry-in to that bit-position unlike the higher ones.)  A [one-instruction computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-instruction_set_computer) with just decrement-and-branch is known to be Turing-complete, but compiling simple programs to that ISA might make huge amounts of code.

Comment: you can build a complete computer with a big box of nand gates...you can choose to make i touring complete or not.  (same goes for nor gates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 4 bit ADD to implement 2 bit AND and XOR simultaneously:

```
 0a0b
+0c0d
=====
 efgh
```

Where:

```
e = a & c
f = a ^ c
g = b & d
h = b ^ d
```

You can implement OR using standard De Morgan.

Comment: But how do you prepare inputs like this, or extract the results, without a right shift?  (ADD same,same is a left shift.)  Also, I think this question is asking how to implement a 4-bit bitwise AND instruction, because they haven't realized that being Turing-complete doesn't mean there's a *convenient* mapping, e.g. they may have to do one bit at a time.

Comment: You just wire the stuff to route bits properly. It's [minecraft](https://minecraft-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Redstone_Wire), I assume it has similar wiring capabilities as normal electric circuits.